# Jump through git diff

Tags: vim, vim-fugitive

I use and love [Tim Pope's excellent Fugitive plugin for VIM](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive), I've always wanted the ability to load up a diff of all of the files in the `:Glog` quickfix and cycles through them to the file in HEAD (or maybe any revision!) individually. Using `:diffthis` doesn't persist the diff when I switch to previous versions and macros seem like a kindof off way to solve it.

Is there a canonical way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is *currently* no way to do this; There are a lot of ways you could make the process relatively painless, and I could definitely script it for you, except for one thing; when you unload the buffer of a `fugitive-revision` in diff mode, fugitive bends over backwards (tpope's own words) to stop the diff in the original file for you.

I *really* like the behaviour you're proposing, so I went ahead and submitted an [issue to the project on GitHub](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/issues/329). Tpope willing, this will be addressed soon, and I'll be more than happy to post a script that will completely automate this behaviour then.